# Disable Windows 10 Update End of Service Spam notification?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, notifications

I've been trying to disable windows 10 updates through traditional means by creating registry entries and editing gpolicy but to no avail. I restart yet I keep getting this end of service update notification. I would like to keep windows update available for new hardware but I don't need the security patches and feature updates at all. I'm not sure on how to get rid of this notification, it keeps appearing every couple of minutes without anyway to hide it. Despite me also disabling all notifications,  this spam end of service notification keeps appearing. Any ideas?
[WINDOWS 10 CONSTANT UPDATE SPAM NOTIFICATION IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Eb8x.png)

I have also tried using this batch script for diabling notifications which I found elsewhere (can't remember where) yet the notification still comes up and takes up the screen.

````
@(echo off% <#%) &color 07 &title Windows Update Notifications-only Toggle, AveYo 2018-2020
set "0=%~f0" &set 1=%*& powershell -nop -c iex ([io.file]::ReadAllText($env:0)) &exit/b ||#>)[1]

$PS = {
 $notify=@()
 $notify += 'MusNotification','MusNotifyIcon'                             # UpdateOrchestrator
 $notify += 'EOSNotify','GWX'                                             # End Of Support
 $notify += 'Windows10UpgraderApp','Windows10Upgrade','WindowsUpdateBox'  # Windows 10 Upgrade
 $notify += 'UpdateNotificationMgr','UNPUXLauncher','UNPUXHost'           # Universal Notification Platform
# OPTIONAL:                                                               # OPTIONAL:
#$notify += 'wermgr','WerFault','WerFaultSecure','DWWIN'                  # Windows Error Reporting
#$notify += 'compattelrunner'                                             # Application Experience
#$notify += 'dstokenclean','appidtel'                                     # ApplicationData
#$notify += 'wsqmcons'                                                    # Customer Experience Improvement Prg
#$notify += 'dusmtask'                                                    # DUSM
#$notify += 'dmclient'                                                    # Feedback\Siuf
#$notify += 'DataUsageLiveTileTask'                                       # {SID}\DataSenseLiveTileTask
#$notify += 'DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Service'                    # System32\DiagSvcs
#$notify += 'HxTsr'                                                       # microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps
#$notify += 'PilotshubApp'                                                # Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_
#$notify += 'SpeechModelDownload','SpeechRuntime'                         # Speech
#$notify += 'LocationNotificationWindows','WindowsActionDialog'           # Location

 $status='Windows Update Notifications ENABLED!'
 $ifeo='HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options'
 if (gp "$ifeo\MusNotification.exe" Debugger -ea 0) {$status='Windows Update Notifications DISABLED!'}
 $dummy="$env:SystemRoot\System32\systray.exe"

# Choice 6 = yes, 7 = no, 2 = cancel
 if ($env:1 -ne 6 -and $env:1 -ne 7) {
   Add-Type -As PresentationFramework;$choice=[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Disable WU Notifications?',$status,3,32);
   if ($choice -eq 2) {exit} else {$c=[int]$choice; $env:1=$c}
 }

# Elevate passing $choice as $env:1
 $i="`r (\   /)`r( * . * )   UAC is useless below Always-Notify`r    ```r"
 $u=0;$w=whoami /groups;if($w-like'*1-5-32-544*'){$u=1};if($w-like'*1-16-12288*'){$u=2};if($w-like'*1-16-16384*'){$u=3}
 if ($u -lt 2) {start powershell -args "-nop -c & {`$i='$i';`$env:1=$c;`$PS={$($PS -replace'"','\"')};& `$PS}" -Verb RunAs;exit}

# Toggle
 if ($env:1 -eq 6) {
   $notify |% {
    kill -name $_ -force -ea 0
    ni "$ifeo\$_.exe" -Force -ea 0|out-null
    sp "$ifeo\$_.exe" Debugger $dummy -Force -ea 0
   }
 } else {
   $notify |% {rp "$ifeo\$_.exe" Debugger -Force -ea 0}
 }

#timeout -1
 exit
}

& $PS
#-_-# hybrid script, can be pasted directly into powershell console
````

Comment: I’ve got limited storage space (very limited) and so this is a throw away machine if you will that I set up for testing, I don’t particularly need these feature updates. I need to stop that notification appearing as it blocks half the screen (since I’m using a low resolution display for this test machine). There’s gotta be a way.

Comment: You have an individual Windows 10 system. Updates cannot be disabled. That is not new but increasingly enforced.

Comment: Any alternatives? What’s the best course of action as I literally only need to disable that single notification in the image I attached.

Comment: I mean, I’ve managed to disable the updates and the update service manually so when I select “Restart Now” nothing happens, the notification disappears then comes back and spams the machine, I could just update it but that defeats the purpose, I’d rather entirely hide the message.

Comment: You might be able make it check in with a dummy or a valid WSUS server and do not approve any updates (or feature updates) in the target group which its a member. I would recommend getting enough space to upgrade by cleaning up with dism, disk cleanup, and even compress the OS with compact OS if you can to get it updated. You can set this all via registry setting or group policy

Comment: I’ve got very specific settings and stuff applied this is just a test machine which I want to use over the next few years without updating, more updates = more space and more potential conflicts so I’d rather block them

Comment: @mya205 - What you want is not possible.

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean 1803 doesn’t have group policy? I was able to enter it fine doing gpedit in Run

Comment: Hmm I see, so I might just update to the newest version that includes this policy update. Which policy would I change then after updating to stop those annoying update notifications from appearing again on the newly updated system?

Comment: See if you can figure out what is generating the notification using task manager.

Comment: @Ramhound which policy change were you talking about earlier? If you could share please

Comment: @Ramhound I believe I’ve found the policy setting you mentioned earlier but it seems even this policy setting doesn’t exempt end of service notifications according to this info: “ If you specify a TargetReleaseVersion the same as the current version, Windows 10 will stay on this version until it reaches end of service.”

Comment: No solution yet, not going to update, hoping someone has a simple solution to this.

Comment: Found a potential solution, just disable the notifications and action Center entirely, Local Computer Policy go to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar. Then in the right pane scroll down and double-click Remove Notifications and Action Center.

Comment: @mya205 - You should submit a detailed answer.

Comment: Nevermind, despite disabling the action center entirely those annoying notification tiles still come up on the screen. Problem persists...

Comment: @mya205 ... Save this https://pastebin.com/AsYMU0ac to a .reg text document and then set those registry settings, reboot, and see if that resolves. I have a Windows 1803 I'm about to upgrade that does not show that annoying notification based on those settings I believe. In this case it's an actual valid WSUS server where the feature update is not approved in WSUS for that target group and thus those settings the notification does not pop up. I'm assuming pointing it to a dummy/invalid WSUS server URL will give the same result but you can apply, reboot, and test to confirm, etc.

Comment: @mya205 I'm sure it's not all those settings but at least the ones with the `http://DummyWSUS:8530` values and the `"DoNotConnectToWindowsUpdateInternetLocations"=dword:00000001` but you can easily adjust, test. and play with them. Setting them all like that should be fine as well in your environment but test as much as you can. You might export what is already in that registry area as a backup before you make adjustment so you have an easy way to revert back if there are problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I found that group policy has an entry allowing all updates to be blocked. For Windows Pro users: open Run and type `gpedit.msc` hit enter and navigate to `User Configurations >> Windows Components >> Windows Updates >> Turn off update features`.

Set it to block updates and to hide notifications from the drop down menu. Now updates will no longer be spammed, if you want to enable it again just set to "Not configured" and if you only want drivers to be updated it's recommended to just search your manufacturer or use a tool such as Driver Booster or Driver Pack Solutions to accomplish this.